# Python-Django. Providing multiple ldap server in python Django settings file

Tags: django, python-2.7

Followed the same syntax mentioned [here](http://django-auth-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/multiconfig.html).

Still can't figure out how to feed two ldap servers in django settings file.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work...
provided server names separated by spaces/commas, both works..
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://ldap.ex1.com ldap://ldap.ex2.com"
 OR
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://ldap.ex1.com, ldap://ldap.ex2.com"